# ipad air only, does not display images when app is compiled in Xcode 6, other iPads are okay

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

We are recompiling our SIMit iPad apps in Xcode 6.1. The apps are working correctly on all iPads tested except the iPad Air. The original version compiled in Xcode 5 works correctly. The iPad Air is not displaying images. The app works so it thinks the images are there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  The bug was related to a UIImageView+Category file that caused the bug with 64-bit processing of UIImageView alpha.  When I deleted it, the problem was gone.  [Images not displaying on iPad AIR, but display on other iPads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238847/images-not-displaying-on-ipad-air-but-display-on-other-ipads)