# Images not displaying on iPad AIR, but display on other iPads

Tags: ios, ipad, air, ios8, xcode6

My images are not displaying on iPad AIRs, but are displaying on other iPads.  They are not displaying in Image views or on buttons.  Besides my images, the Segmented Control image is also not displaying, although I can still tap on the buttons and segmented control where I know they exist on the UI.   I found that background images on my buttons do display, but an image on my buttons do not. Maybe this will help - I think this started after I got the message about required 64 bit support as of 2/1/15 (during Validation), recommending me to change the default build setting to 'Standard Architecture'. After making this recommended change, the images stopped showing.

In Build Settings, under Architectures: Before: $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) After: Standard Architectures (armv7, arm64)

When I changed it back, the images started displaying again.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the bug, related to 64-bit processing on iPad Air.  I had a UIImageView+Category file to try and always show the vertical scroll bar.  This file caused the problem, I removed it to fix the bug.  Hope this helps someone else out.  Thanks

```
@implementation UIImageView (ForScrollView)

- (void) setAlpha:(float)alpha {

    if (self.superview.tag == noDisableVerticalScrollTag) {
        if (alpha == 0 && self.autoresizingMask == UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin) {
            if (self.frame.size.width < 10 && self.frame.size.height > self.frame.size.width) {
                UIScrollView *sc = (UIScrollView*)self.superview;
                if (sc.frame.size.height < sc.contentSize.height) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (self.superview.tag == noDisableHorizontalScrollTag) {
        if (alpha == 0 && self.autoresizingMask == UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin) {
            if (self.frame.size.height < 10 && self.frame.size.height < self.frame.size.width) {
                UIScrollView *sc = (UIScrollView*)self.superview;
                if (sc.frame.size.width < sc.contentSize.width) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [super setAlpha:alpha];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. I was disappointed after some research as this seemed to be really strange. And it was.
For me, **restarting my Mac helped**… Yes, not the answer you would want but that did the trick. Cleaning, Deleting Derived data, Xcode restart etc. before with no effect.